# If the English word "obliterate" really comes from Latin "oblitteratus" (erased, forgotten), why is there no double t in the English word?

Tags: etymology, orthography

The English word "obliterate" allegedly comes from Latin "oblitteratus" (erased, forgotten), itself from "ob-" (against) and "littera" (letter of the alphabet). [Here is its page on etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/obliterate#etymonline_v_2431). But, if that's true, why doesn't the English word "obliterate" contain a double t, to be *oblitterate, like Latin "oblitteratus"? Was it borrowed through French, which lost geminate consonants rather early (so to be for the same reason as there is no double-m in "flame", even if it comes from Latin "flamma"), or?

Comment: The Etymonline entry you link to says the Latin only has (or can have) only one *t,* and certainly doesn't mention *oblitteratus* with a double consonant. It seems to be your answer: what is unclear about it?

Comment: This seems like a question about Latin etymology, since *obliteratus* is a Latin word.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP misread the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, any word derived from the root of the Latin word *littera* is spelled with *liter-* in English: examples are *literature, literate, literary, literal.* (*Letter* itself is an exception, since it is a less learned formation.) I don't know exactly why this spelling became established.  Although the double *-tt-* spelling *littera* is supposed to have been usual in Classical Latin, variant spellings with single *-t-* seem to have existed from fairly early on. (The ultimate origin of Latin *littera* is debated: many scholars think the double /tt/ form developed out of an earlier form with single /t/, but others disagree with that explanation.)

---

It looks like the earliest attestations in English of the word *literature*, from the 15th century, show both *-t-* and *-tt-* spellings, so I think these words in general previously showed variation in spelling between *-t-* and *-tt-* in English.

I don't think the modern English habit of using *-t-* spellings to the exclusion of *-tt-* spellings in this family of words goes back to French: Modern French uses spellings with double *-tt-* in related words like *littéraire* and *littérature.* However, it seems Middle French may have showed variation, as in Middle English, between *-t-* and *-tt-* spellings (which would have been pronounced identically). The OED entry for *literal* mentions "Middle French *literal, litteral*", for *literary* mentions "Middle French *literaire, litteraire*". The TLFi etymology sections for *[littéraire](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/litt%C3%A9raire)* and *[littéral](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/litt%C3%A9ral)* cite historical examples of single-t spellings, "1527 œuvre literaire" and "Début xiv<sup>e</sup>s. *science literale* « les belles-lettres, les lettres » (Aimé de Mont-Cassin, Histoire des Normands, éd. N. de Bartholomaeis, p. 217)"

As for the situation in Late Latin, Buzássyová 2016 gives the following summary:

> The word *lit(t)era* was originally written with a long vowel or the diphthong *ei* and one *t*, which then (around 200 B.C.) turned into a sequence of a short vowel and double *t* (the so-called *rule littera* or *Iuppi­ter*). Thanks to the etymologies of Roman grammarians deriving the meaning of the word *lit(t)era* from *litura* or *legitera,* the original way of spelling with one *t* came into use again. The chapters in *Artes gram­maticae* may therefore, according to the preferences of the author, have the headings *De litera* or *De littera,* and *De literis* or *De litteris.*

(Ľudmila Buzássyová, "[The ‘Phonetic Complex’ in Renaissance Latin Grammar: Petrus Ramus’s Dichotomies and Their Reflections in Two Vernacular Grammatical Texts](https://www.academia.edu/36286001/The_Phonetic_Complex_in_Renaissance_Latin_Grammar_Petrus_Ramuss_Dichotomies_and_Their_Reflections_in_Two_Vernacular_Grammatical_Texts)", *Graeco-Latina Brunensia* (Bratislava) 21, no. 2, page 82. As you see, Buzássyová subscribes to the hypothesis that a single-t form of *lit(t)era* was original, but says that the use of single-t spellings in later Latin texts was due to etymological theories of the writers.)

To sum up, then, it seems like *t* and *tt* spellings in *littera* and its derivatives coexisted to some extent as early as Latin (although *tt* was clearly the dominant spelling in Classical Latin). In Middle French, spellings with *t* and *tt* seem to have coexisted (I'm not sure what their relative frequencies were), and Middle English showed similar variation between *t* and *tt*. For reasons unclear to me, *t* rather than *tt* became the established spelling when modern English spelling conventions became fixed.

Those authors who played a role in standardizing the single *t* spelling in English presumably also used single *t* in the corresponding Latin words. Thus, Samuel Johnson's dictionary of 1755 has entries like

- [ILLI'TERATE](https://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/views/search.php?term=illiterate). adj.  [*illiteratus,* Latin.]
- [Li'terature](https://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/views/search.php?term=literature). n.s.  [*literatura,* Latin.]
- To [OBLI'TERATE](https://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/views/search.php?term=obliterate). v.a.  [*oblitero, ob* and *litera,* Latin.]

None of this poses a problem to deriving *obliterate* from Latin *oblitteratus, obliteratus*: it simply comes from the second of these two alternative spellings of the same word.

Here are some Google Books results showing that spellings with "oblitt-" existed in English in the 17th century:

- [1638 oblitterated](https://books.google.com/books?id=mlJBAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA213&dq=oblitterated&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjozYmTl-qBAxVHLzQIHZt0CdoQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=oblitterated&f=false)
- [1628 oblitterated](https://books.google.com/books?id=ykpLAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA32&dq=oblitterated&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjozYmTl-qBAxVHLzQIHZt0CdoQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=oblitterated&f=false)
- [1666 oblitterate](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cu1iAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA101&dq=oblitterated&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjozYmTl-qBAxVHLzQIHZt0CdoQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=oblitterated&f=false)
- [1643 oblitterate](https://books.google.com/books?id=DyhUzg_eK80C&pg=PA169&dq=oblitterate&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxt5OMl-qBAxVkMX0KHTPaBPYQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Latin had two forms of _obliterate_ both with a single and a double 't' per _OED_: _oblīterāt-_ and _oblitterāt-_. However, the etymon of _obliterate_ is _oblīterāt-_ so there is no consonant alteration when borrowed. If we are talking about the etymology of Latin _oblīterāt-_, which comes from _littera_, there was also the form _litera_.